# How to make "Real number symbol" (ℝ) in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica, symbols

How can I write the "Real number symbol" `ℝ` in Mathematica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with <kbd>esc</kbd>dsR<kbd>esc</kbd>
You could also replace `R` with any letters from a-z, both uppercase and lowercase, to get the double-struck version of the letter.

Another way is writing `\[DoubleStruckCapitalR]` or whatever character you want to be double-struck.

Reference:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NotationalAlphabetCharacters.html#647579870